# Get a new list of a custom type using a Group by

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of a custom type called Holding. I am trying to use LNIQ to query certain values from this list. I would a new list of type Holding returned.

Below is the line I currently have which does not work.

```
List<Holding> hlds = _holdingList
    .Where(hld => hld.IdSedol == lookThroList[i].Sedol)
    .GroupBy(hld => new Holding())
    .ToList();
```

By changing the line above to `var hlds =` does work and produce the correct result. Why can I not cast or do something to make the first line work?

Also the line below I'm not entirely sure about. The Holding object that is returned will that reference the holding object in my original list or is it a new object?

```
GroupBy(hld => new Holding())
```

**Update**

The reason I was using GroupBy (wrongly by the looks of it) was because I didn't want multiple fund codes that are the same, just wanted where the fund codes are different. However as I think about it I do not need to group by.

Comment: Why do you use `.GroupBy(hld => new Holding())`?

Comment: If I had to guess, the `.GroupBy(hld => new Holding())`part will not group anything, because it groups by freshly created (empty and similar) objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like this is all you need:

```
List<Holding> hlds = _holdingList
    .Where(hld => hld.IdSedol == lookThroList[i].Sedol)
    .ToList();
```

`GroupBy()` will never produce a collection of `Holding`s.
In your code, `GroupBy()` will produce an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Holding, Holding>>`.

If you want to filter out duplicates, you can do this (assuming the `Holding` class has a `FundCode` property or something similar):

```
List<Holding> hlds = _holdingList
          .Where(hld => hld.IdSedol == lookThroList[i].Sedol)
          .GroupBy(hld => hld.FundCode)
          .Select(g => g.First())
          .ToList();
```

Linq also has a `Distinct()` method, but that usually requires defining an `IEqualityComparer` and that might be overkill in this case.

Comment: thanks for a very clear answer. I know linq is quite simple to most people but I don't really get it. Need to read up I think

Comment: @mHelpMe Just stick with it and you'll get it soon enough. :)